# Thread clarification in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized

**Is it possible to synchronize the method when we extend `Thread` rather than implementing `Runnable`?**

I know that when we use `Runnable`, it is possible. But when we do `Thread t1 = new Thread();`, can this be done?

How can it be synchronized?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your code (using Runnable)?

Comment: You can do all the things with `Thread` which can be done by `Runnable` except that you can not extend any other class if you extend a class with `Thread`.

Answer (score 4):

Synchronization is orthogonal to the class on which the method is defined. You can use `synchronized` in *any* method. It just means there's a mutex guarding that block of code.

```
public class MyTotallyUnspecialClass {
    synchronized public void someTotallyUnspecialMethod() {
        // this method is synchronized, with a mutex on "this"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no effect on synchronization whether you extend Thread or implement Runnable. When you synchronize a method , you get a lock on the OBJECT and not the thread - so it really does not matter.There are many SO topics that discuss the distinction between these 2 approaches (extending thread vs implementing Runnable)